# Byte to Character transformation in python

Tags: python

Using the following code I was able to convert characters to bits:

```
msg= bitarray(endian='little')
msg.frombytes(b'ABCDEFGH')
```

How to convert it back bits to characters?

**NOTE:** This pertains to the [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) package.

Comment: Is `bitarray` from the [`bitarray` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/)?

Comment: Yes it is from bitarray, called by "from bitarray import bitarray".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bitarray` object has a `tobytes()` method as well:

```
bytes_value = msg.tobytes()
```