# How to left shift a bitarray in python

Tags: python, des

I have a bit array named `c0` containing 28 bits

```
bitarray('1111011111111111111111110001')
```

how can I left shift this bit array for a number of times, meaning one left shift, two left shift, etc.? 
One left shift is fine for now!

**NOTE:** This pertains to the [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) package.

Comment: There's no `bitarray` in standard Python. Are you using the [PyPI package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) of the same name?

Comment: Is it https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/ ?

Comment: `<<` and `>>` are the shift operators (the bitarray class should override the `__ilshift__` and `__irshift__` methods

Comment: @SimeonVisser: [We can assume so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642820/byte-to-character-transformation-in-python)

Comment: @SimeonVisser :Yes, It is bitarray. Could You give me a code that just implements one left shift In an example?

Comment: @MikeMcMahon: `__ilshift__` and `__irshift__` are the in-place hooks; you'd have to implement the `__lshift__` and `__rshift__` hooks too, with Python falling back to the latter if the former are not available.

Comment: whoopsie, my bad, you are correct! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use slicing:

```
def leftshift(ba, count):
    return ba[count:] + (bitarray('0') * count)

def rightshift(ba, count):
    return (bitarray('0') * count) + ba[:-count]
```

These maintain the bit-width of the input, dropping bits on one end and padding with `0` on the other.

You can create your own subclass of the `bitarray` type:

```
class mybitarray(bitarray):
    def __lshift__(self, count):
        return self[count:] + type(self)('0') * count
    def __rshift__(self, count):
        return type(self)('0') * count + self[:-count]
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}('{}')".format(type(self).__name__, self.to01())
```

Demo:

```
>>> c0 = mybitarray(c0)
>>> c0
mybitarray('1111011111111111111111110001')
>>> c0 << 4
mybitarray('0111111111111111111100010000')
>>> c0 >> 4
mybitarray('0000111101111111111111111111')
```

You can also poke the author to [support these operations natively](https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray/issues/7).

Answer (score 1):

`<<` and `>>` are the shift operators (the bitarray class should override the `__ilshift__` and `__irshift__` methods.

Comment: This is a *third party* library, written in C.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Third party libraries written in C can very well overload operators. The C syntax for overloading is different, but the resulting objects should have a `__rshift__` attribute for instance, so this technicality is only important for the writer of the extension module. The only missing piece is an assertion (or better, reference) that it *does*.

Comment: there are a few bitarray classes for python floating around.  Some are pure python and implement the shift, others do not.  Need to know more.

Comment: @delnan: Correction, it does not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then complain about that, not about the fact that it's third party and written in C ;-) All assuming OP does use the package we're assuming and not the one Mike McMahon assumes.

Comment: @delnan: The OP asked a question about the same library earlier today. See [Byte to Character transformation in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20642820)